# Getting data from SQL Server thorugh php and making it in json format

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, json

I'm trying to make a UI that gets its data from a SQL Server database. I want to get it through PHP. Currently, I'm able to make database connection and insert the data through the following code

```html
<?php
  
$serverName = "esdapocnv01";
$connectionInfo = array( 'Database'=>'TRG_TEST', 'UID'=>'testuser', 'PWD'=>'Towing@2');

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 
}



$class = $_POST['number'];
$teachers=$_POST['teachers1'];
$rooms=$_POST['rooms1'];

$sql = "insert into school(class,teachers,rooms) values ('$class','$teachers','$rooms') ";



$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['station'] . "'>" . $row['station'] . "</option>";
                               
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

Now I want to get data from the database table and convert it into JSON format so that I can use it in the UI

Comment: Take a look at json_encode : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: have you tried some thing or googled? just showing your code and asking for answer is bad practice.

Comment: ye si have googled i am very new to php so found no other way

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data1.php", 
    data: {"id": "EMP001"},
    success: function(result){

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
        alert( obj.name );

    }
});
```

**data1.php**

```
<?php
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_employee` WHERE `id`='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
       $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);
?>
```

Comment: push the data to an array and use json_encode(). you will get the data in json format

Comment: if i want the json to be in ceratin format how to achieve that??

Comment: in what format do you need? you can manipulate as per your need with the array

Comment: if i have many variable that are to be taken inside an array of another variable how to do that

Comment: now if i have to call it in javascript do you have any idea how to call it

Comment: so you are trying to send the request in ajax to php and you need to decode the json data in js. Is that right?

Comment: yes i'll be using either jquery or angularjs to enter those data in my UI

Comment: so you saying that emparray will be converted into json format and if i ahve to call it by jquery i can call it by parse.JSON??

Comment: actually i have my php code in another file called data1.php how can i call it in script.js

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select * from tbl_employee";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
       $a['class']=$row['class'];
       $a['teacher']=$row['teachers'];
       $a['room']=$row['rooms'];
       $a['addedat']=Now(); //example of adding extra data if required
       $b[]=$a;
    }
    echo json_encode($b);
?>
```

Comment: are you adding all data into an array and converting it into json??